# Loading custom fonts from a URL in NativeScript

Tags: fonts, font-face, nativescript

NativeScript supports using custom fonts that are packaged in the app's `app/fonts` directory. One refers to them with CSS `font-family` rules. I need to be able to use a custom font that is loaded from a web site at run time.

In native Android, one can load a font more or less directly from a web address (just open an input stream to the URL and feed it to the `Typeface` constructor).  In iOS, it's also possible (as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942449/ios-programmatically-add-custom-font-during-runtime)). Is there any support for doing something similar in NS (use a custom font loaded from the web), other than dropping down into native code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually is pretty simple to do in NativeScript; however there is a gotcha if you don't want to duplicate any code.  You must put the fonts in the /app/fonts folder, even the ones you download.

Your steps are:

1. Download the font to the `/app/fonts/` folder, you can use any valid method to download it/them.
   Unfortunately, the font registration system looks for any custom fonts in the fonts folder; so unless you want to "duplicate" the registration code in your own code base; just drop the new fonts into the `/app/fonts/` folder.
2. Register the font for ios:

`if (!global.android) {
   var fonts = require('ui/styling/fonts');
   fonts.ios.registerFont('MyFont.ttf'); // or .otf
}`

3. Assign a `MyFont` directly to the item's style property; (i.e. `SomeLabel.style.fontFamily = "MyFont";`)

or

3. assign the font-family to a css value; and then assign the css 
   `Page.addCss('MyCoolFont { font-family: myFont; }");` to the `SomeLabel.cssClass = 'myCoolFont';`

Comment: I guess I'm too stuck in Android development mode, where the app's resources are read-only. I didn't even think of simply putting the font file into `app/fonts`. Thanks!

Comment: For future-proofing, wouldn't it be better to test `if (global.ios)` instead of `if (!global.android)`?

Comment: Yeah, I put a suggestion in to the NS team over a year ago to publish a `global.ios` in the ios engine, but they disagreed with me.   I still think they are wrong. :-)      You can use `global.android` on android...  Other platforms don't have as convenient of a method.   You can `require ('platforms')` and detect it that way, or you can use things like: `if (typeof NSString !== 'undefined' && typeof NSObject !== 'undefined') //  on ios`