# How to allow a user to import and use a custom font in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

I would like to allow users to import their own fonts into my app. I've got the importing part covered through the "Open In" menu, but how would I go about installing the imported font to be used within the app?

Comment: Sure, you can use custom font without declare it in plist file, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942449/ios-programmatically-add-custom-font-during-runtime)

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it.