# How to set font from url programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How to set font from url programmatically? I have font url which I am getting from API response, like this : "https://phoenixlab.in/uploads/font/Poppins-Medium.ttf". I need to set this font in `UIlabel` text in Swift.

Comment: Download the file, first?

Comment: @ElTomato After download what i need to do?

Comment: Duplicated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942449/ios-programmatically-add-custom-font-during-runtime

Comment: @CloudBalancing I am talking about from server url.

Answer (score 1):

Your app cannot download an arbitrary font and start using it. On the contrary, all nonstandard fonts except Apple's must be included / listed in the app at review time.